# Updating Laravel/Lumen API Using Git and Github

Tags: laravel, git, github, lumen

Please notice Im new to Git

I have a Laravel-Lumen API project for Mobile Application, Almost I finished all the required functions of the project and **push** it to Github repository form my local PC and **clone** it on ubuntu server for production and every thing works great now.

Today I need to make some changes in some function to change its output so I made the changes on my local PC **commit** and **push** the changes and on ubuntu server I made **git pull** and I noticed that my changes took effect and the function output changes and the application still working fine.

My question is : Is that a safe and good approach to make changes on production environment and projects ?

Update : to be more specific my changes only affect the functions in the Controllers and not messing with the Database structure and tables.

Answer (score 0):

I often create one more source code branch: `staging` for testing. I will want to merge `staging` into `production` when i need to release a new version of API

I using [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io) to do that process automatically

By the way, you maybe want to have a look at [Apify](https://github.com/megaads-vn/apify), i using APIfy for Mobile Application development. It's easy and friendly